# How to get Date from a String in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to get date from a give string. Suppose we have a string 09-Dec-2016 12:00:00 AM I want to display only 30-Dec-2016

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);

       // String strCurrentDate = "Wed, 18 Apr 2012 07:55:29 +0000";
        String strCurrentDate = "30-Dec-2016 12:00:00 AM";
       // SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z");
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z");
        Date newDate = null;
        try {
            newDate = format.parse(strCurrentDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a");
        String date = format.format(newDate);
        textView.setText(date);


    }
```

I want to display date like this 30-Dec-2016

Comment: Is there any who could help?

Comment: Date changed from 9 to 30. That's some time traveling.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: read your question....then you know what AlphaQ means....

Comment: Changed it thatks AlphaQ

Comment: if your date only should display day, month and year, your SimpleDateFormat has to be `("dd-MMM-yyyy");` , but if you really want to jump from 9th to 30th of month, then just add the days to the date and then format it...

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a");
Date date = sdf.parse(inputDateString);
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String outputString  = sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: When want to give it to the textview getting nullpointerException.
Doesn't solve my issue sir.

Comment: check whether your textview is null or the date string is null and handle the null pointer exception.Also add the parse exception to the date and handle it.

Answer (score 0):

**Do this:**

```
String currDate = "09-Dec-2016 12:00:00 AM";
String date = currDate.split("\\s")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Date String_date(String date) 
{
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk-mm");
    Date myDate = null;
    try {
        myDate = dateFormat.parse(date);

        return myDate;

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return myDate;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    String strCurrentDate = "30-Dec-2016 12:00:00 AM";
    SimpleDateFormat formatParse = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a",Locale.getDefault());
    Date newDate = null;
    try {
        newDate = formatParse.parse(strCurrentDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    String date = format.format(newDate);
    textView.setText(date);
```

ps.
[formats eg.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP684.png)

Answer (score 0):

//parse Date từ Date sang String
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

```
        Date newdate = new Date(Long.parseLong(tt.getThoiGian()));



        format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String date1 = format.format(newdate);
        txtThoiGian.setText(date1);
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String date1 = format.format(newdate);
        txtThoiGian.setText(date1);

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. Also, please edit your comment into your question. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).